# Optimal way to select data in a tree

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following table relationship.

`[Organisation] 1--* [UserOrganisationPermission] *--1 [User]`

Finding a list of `Organisation` for a `User` is obvious pretty easy...

```
select O.Id
from UserOrganisationPermission p
join Organisation o on p.OrganisationId = o.Id
where p.UserId = @SomeUserId
```

My `Organisation` table is self-referencing via a `ParentId` column, enabling me to have a tree-like structure of organisations.

If the `User` has permission to an `Organisation` then they implicitly have been granted permission to all organisations down the tree.

I need to find a way of easily selecting those organisations.

So far I have tried adding a `Path varchar(900)` column to the `Organisation` table that contains a delimited list of int Ids in its path. It works like this

1. Whenever a new `Organisation` is inserted: If it's `ParentId` is `null` then its `Path` is simply `-id-`, if `ParentId` is not `null` then it's `Path` is its parent's `Path` with `id-` appended.
2. Whenever an `Organisation` is updated: If its `ParentId` has changed then I perform an `Update Organisation` command that selects all `Path` columns that started with its previous path value, and replaces that part of the `Path` with the new path.

e.g.

1. Path `-1-`
2. Path `-1-2-`
3. Path `-1-2-3`

If I change the `ParentId` of `2` to `null` it will update all `Organisation` rows that have a `Path` starting with `-1-2-` and replace `-1-2-` with `-2-`

1. Path `-1-`
2. Path `-2-`
3. Path `-2-3`

This way I can select all `Organisation` sub nodes like so

```
select O.Id
where O.Path like '-2-%`
```

Which would give me `-2-` and `-2-3-`.

I can't help but think there is a far more simple way of achieving this goal. Is there a far more simple way I am missing?

[image: DB structure]

Comment: Can you share the structure of table UserOrganisationPermission and maybe a bit of sample data ?

Comment: Presumably you're going to need to use an rCTE here.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to build your path with a recursive cte in stead of maintaning it in an actual column.

Maybe this [updated DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8c98d6b7eed63f206fb3731ba4b1ea3) can get you started

```
with Hierarchy(id, parentid, Path) as
( select o.id, o.parentid, convert(varchar(max), o.id)
  from organisation o
    left join organisation o2 on o.parentid = o2.id
  where o.parentid is null
  union all
  select o.id, o.parentid, convert(varchar(max), s.Path + '-' + o.id)
  from  Hierarchy s
    inner join organisation o on s.id = o.parentid  
)
select s.id, s.parentid, '-' + s.Path + '-'
from   Hierarchy s
order by id
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

result is

| id | parentid | Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | -1- |
| 2 | 1 | -1-2- |
| 3 | 2 | -1-2-3- |
| 4 |  | -4- |
| 5 | 4 | -4-5- |